# Updating an entry record programatically?

Tags: plugin-development, entry

I need to update the value of an entry attribute programatically. I've tried a couple things, but the record is not updated. The code I am using is below.

```
      $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
      $criteria->section = 'affiliates';          
      $criteria->limit = null;
      $criteria -> search ='email:'.$email;
      $criteria = $criteria -> first();

      $criteria->getContent()->setAttribute("optOut", "true");

      craft()->entries->saveEntry($criteria);
      return $criteria->title;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you call `$criteria->first()`, you no longer have an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), but an actual [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel), so probably more semantic to change to:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'affiliates';          
$criteria->limit = null;
$criteria -> search ='email:'.$email;
$entry = $criteria->first();

$entry->getContent()->setAttribute("optOut", "true");

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
return $entry->title;
```

But my guess about your actual problem is you're getting a validation error.  You can verify and guard against that in your code by doing something like:

```
if (craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry))
{
    return $entry->title;
}
else
{
    $errors = $entry->getErrors();
}
```